# Cluster Comparing in 2d lidar scans

Tags: c#, lidar

Can anybody let me know how I can compare two scans with different clusters in them. I have attached a picture showing both of the scans. I want to keep the clusters which are present in both the scans.

[image: Both scans with different clusters]

Comment: What have you tried so far? What potential methods have you researched? How well does the two datasets correspond, i.e. are the two sets identical? offset by a constant? scaled by a constant? some arbitrary transform between the sets?

Comment: There is no offset To make it in one window i just put the two scans one above the other. I really dont know which method to use because there are no features. Only thing i can try is to measure the distance between the two cluster. But the problem is if these two clusters are identical or nearly same or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the two sets contain the same points ( possibly with some noise added), but one of the sets contains extra points.

It should then be fairly simple to check the distance from each point in set A to each point in set B. If there is any point within some radius can mark the point as part of both set A and B. This kind of search will probably benefit greatly from some kind of search structure, like a Kd-Tree, or some other optimization approach.

Without more details it is difficult to provide a more detailed suggestion.

Comment: This can let me know if there is a cluster within that range but I was trying to check the similarity between them. like if they are close to each other in both scans but also a check if they are almost like 90% similar or something like that.

Comment: you could check the percentage of points that match between the sets.